# C# Entity Framework many-to-many relations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, codefirst

У меня есть класс Student, который содержит информацию о студентах, а так же  клас Group, который содержит описания факультета.
Один студент может посещать много факультетов, а так же одои факультет может посещать множество студентов. Связь многие-ко-многим.

```
 public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Group> GroupId { get; set; }
}



public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string NameOfGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> StudentId { get; set; }
}
```

Как я понимаю, будет создана промежуточная таблица Student/Group, которая будет хранить два внешних ключа. Но кроме этих двух внешних ключей мне нужно добавить еще поле DateOfJoin (Дата записи в факультет). Как это сделать?

Comment: Ну а в коде это как будет выглядеть? Опишите контекст данных, какие в нем будут поля, какие классы будут использоваться?

Comment: Отказывайтесь от связи многие-ко-многим и реализуйте промежуточную таблицу самостоятельно (с двумя связями один-ко-многим), добавляйте в нее любые дополнительные поля.

Comment: [То, что вам надо.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application#create-the-data-model)